# Mouse wheel doesn't scroll after update 18.04.3 (4.15.0-62-generic)

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-scroll

I've tried resetting GNOME settings, as I thought that was connected, but it  had nothing to do with it.

Tried xev tool, and no events were fired for mouse scrolling.

Touchpad scrolling works fine.

I tried changing some setting for mouse (natural scrolling on/off) but this didn't bring the scrolling for the mouse back.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to kernel 4.15.0-58-generic worked!
You can choose it from GRUB menu (Advanced options).

Anyone can advise on what to do when the next update of kernel arrives and still has no fix for that?

The bug report and more info here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1843323